# Sheva and Dedan

Tags: names, tanach, genesis-bereishith

Is there any connection between Sheva and Dedan, sons of Yokshan ben Avraham ([Beresheet 25:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.25.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0), [Divrei Hayamim 1:1:32](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.1.32?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)) and Sheva and Dedan, sons of Ra'ama ben Cush ([Beresheet 10:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.10?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0))?